# Sorting a list in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have this code that generates a list with products and prices , this list is showed without order and I am trying to order it by price.

I have used asort($items) to get this done but it did not work, I do not know why.

Here is the code, any help is appreciated:

```
<?php $currencyd = 'U$S';  asort($items);?> 
<?php foreach ($items as $key => $item): ?> 
<a rel="nofollow" class="list-group-item" target="_blank" 
href=" <?php echo esc_url($item['url']) ?>"
    <?php echo $item['ga_event'] ?>  
<img src="<?php echo esc_attr(TemplateHelper::getMerhantIconUrl($item, false)); ?>" /> 
<?php echo \esc_html($item['domain']); ?>
    <?php if ($item['price']): ?>
    <span style="background-color: #575354;" class="cegg-price cegg-price-badge">
<?php echo TemplateHelper::formatPriceCurrency($item['price_raw'], $currencyd ); ?></span>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </a>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

Comment: And what is your $items query ?